# refresh images in ipad from xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an ios app for iphone and ipad, and I can't seem to find a option to do a particular task.

I had filler images (just colored squares) in the project before the designer provided the actual images, but when I switch the images (changed the file in finder) they dont get updated to the my ipad (or even the simulator).

I tried deleting the app from the device and running the code again but it didn't work either.

Is there a way to flush the graphical contents of a project? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the clean build. Product - Clean, then build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the file in finder won't work. You need to either drag the images into the Xcode window for your project, or right click in your project and select "Add Files" to select the images to add (make sure to check the "Copy the items into destination group's folder" option).

Comment: Yes, but the file already exists. For example I have a file called Pavillion~ipad.png that is a simple orange square and is used in the project. If i replace the file with another, now with an icon, the file does not get pushed to the device. I assume that xcode does not notice that the file changed. I'm trying to force xcode to push the file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is by design or simply my own problem, but I managed to solve this.

I had to delete the app from the device via the **organizer**. If I deleted via the device it still didn't work.